# How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have a date string of the form '2009/05/13 19:19:30 -0400'. It seems that previous versions of Python may have supported a %z format tag in strptime for the trailing timezone specification, but 2.6.x seems to have removed that.

What's the right way to parse this string into a datetime object?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can use the parse function from dateutil:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> d = parse('2009/05/13 19:19:30 -0400')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 13, 19, 19, 30, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))
```

This way you obtain a datetime object you can then use.

As [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804505/dateutil-parser-parse-gives-error-initial-value-must-be-unicode-or-none-not/7804999#7804999), dateutil2.0 is written for Python 3.0 and does not work with Python 2.x. For Python 2.x dateutil1.5 needs to be used.

Comment: This works fine for me (`dateutil` 2.1) with Python `2.7.2`; Python 3 isn't required. Note that if you're installing from pip, the package name is `python-dateutil`.

Answer (score 61):

`%z` is supported in Python 3.2+:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2009/05/13 19:19:30 -0400', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %z')
datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 13, 19, 19, 30,
                  tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000)))
```

On earlier versions:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '2009/05/13 19:19:30 -0400'
naive_date_str, _, offset_str = date_str.rpartition(' ')
naive_dt = datetime.strptime(naive_date_str, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
offset = int(offset_str[-4:-2])*60 + int(offset_str[-2:])
if offset_str[0] == "-":
   offset = -offset
dt = naive_dt.replace(tzinfo=FixedOffset(offset))
print(repr(dt))
# -> datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 13, 19, 19, 30, tzinfo=FixedOffset(-240))
print(dt)
# -> 2009-05-13 19:19:30-04:00
```

where `FixedOffset` is a class based on [the code example from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.fromutc):

```
from datetime import timedelta, tzinfo

class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    """Fixed offset in minutes: `time = utc_time + utc_offset`."""
    def __init__(self, offset):
        self.__offset = timedelta(minutes=offset)
        hours, minutes = divmod(offset, 60)
        #NOTE: the last part is to remind about deprecated POSIX GMT+h timezones
        #  that have the opposite sign in the name;
        #  the corresponding numeric value is not used e.g., no minutes
        self.__name = '<%+03d%02d>%+d' % (hours, minutes, -hours)
    def utcoffset(self, dt=None):
        return self.__offset
    def tzname(self, dt=None):
        return self.__name
    def dst(self, dt=None):
        return timedelta(0)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'FixedOffset(%d)' % (self.utcoffset().total_seconds() / 60)
```

Comment: This causes a `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %M:%H:%S.%f %z'` in my case (Python 2.7).

Comment: @Sheljohn it is not supposed to work on Python 2.7 Look  at the very top of the answer.

Comment: weird, by the way, that this is NOT AT ALL mentioned on Python *2.7* docs: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 26):

Here is a fix of the `"%z"` issue for Python 2.7 and earlier

Instead of using:

```
datetime.strptime(t,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M %z')
```

Use the `timedelta` to account for the timezone, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
def dt_parse(t):
    ret = datetime.strptime(t[0:16],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
    if t[18]=='+':
        ret-=timedelta(hours=int(t[19:22]),minutes=int(t[23:]))
    elif t[18]=='-':
        ret+=timedelta(hours=int(t[19:22]),minutes=int(t[23:]))
    return ret
```

Note that the dates would be converted to `GMT`, which would allow doing date arithmetic without worrying about time zones.

Comment: I like this, though you need to change 'seconds=' to 'minutes='.

Comment: Just as a note, if you wanted to take a timezone in a string, and convert the datetime to UTC, you would use the opposite logic listed here.  If the timezone has a +, you subtract the timedelta, and vice-versa.

Comment: The transformation to UTC was wrong, if there is a `+` character the timedelta should be **substracted**, and vice-versa. I have edited and corrected the code.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with using dateutil is that you can't have the same format string for both serialization and deserialization, as dateutil has limited formatting options (only `dayfirst` and `yearfirst`).

In my application, I store the format string in .INI file, and each deployment can have its own format. Thus, I really don't like the dateutil approach.

Here's an alternative method that uses pytz instead:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from pytz import timezone, utc
from pytz.tzinfo import StaticTzInfo

class OffsetTime(StaticTzInfo):
    def __init__(self, offset):
        """A dumb timezone based on offset such as +0530, -0600, etc.
        """
        hours = int(offset[:3])
        minutes = int(offset[0] + offset[3:])
        self._utcoffset = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes)

def load_datetime(value, format):
    if format.endswith('%z'):
        format = format[:-2]
        offset = value[-5:]
        value = value[:-5]
        return OffsetTime(offset).localize(datetime.strptime(value, format))

    return datetime.strptime(value, format)

def dump_datetime(value, format):
    return value.strftime(format)

value = '2009/05/13 19:19:30 -0400'
format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %z'

assert dump_datetime(load_datetime(value, format), format) == value
assert datetime(2009, 5, 13, 23, 19, 30, tzinfo=utc) \
    .astimezone(timezone('US/Eastern')) == load_datetime(value, format)
```

Answer (score 5):

One liner for old Pythons out there. You can multiply a timedelta by 1/-1 depending on +/- sign, as in:

```
datetime.strptime(s[:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') + timedelta(hours=int(s[20:22]), minutes=int(s[23:])) * (-1 if s[19] == '+' else 1)
```

Answer (score -10):

If you are on Linux, then you can use the external `date` command to dwim:

```
import commands, datetime

def parsedate(text):
  output=commands.getoutput('date -d "%s" +%%s' % text )
  try:
      stamp=eval(output)
  except:
      print output
      raise
  return datetime.datetime.frometimestamp(stamp)
```

This is of course less portable than dateutil, but slightly more flexible, because `date` will also accept inputs like "yesterday" or "last year" :-)

Comment: I don't think it is good to call an external programm for this. And the next weak point: eval(): If you now that a webserver executes this code, you could do arbitrary code execution on the server!

Comment: It all depends on the context: if what we're after is only a write-and-throw-away script, then these weaknesses are just irrelevant :-)

Comment: Down-voting this because: 1) It makes a system call for something trivial, 2) It injects strings directly into a shell call, 3) It calls eval(), and 4) It has an exception catch-all. Basically this is an example of how *not* to do things.

Comment: In this case, though eval is evil and shouldn't be used. an external call seems to be the easiest and most practical way to get a unix timestamp from a timezone aware datestring, where the timezone is not a numeric offset.

Comment: Well, again, this "eval is evil" motto really depends on your context (which was not stated by the OP). When I write scripts for my own use, I use eval liberally, and it's awesome. Python is a great language for glue scripts ! Of course you can roll out convoluted general-case over-engineered solutions like in some answers above, and then claim it's-the-only-right-way-to-do-it, ala Java. But for many use-cases a quick-and-dirty solution is just as good.