# Python - strptime format with unknown behavior

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a time format:

```
Sat Jan 17 04:33:06 +0000 2015
```

that I can't match to a strptime format. The closest I can find: [basic datetime types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) is %c "Locale’s appropriate date and time representation." However, this doesn't exactly match.

I'm going for:

```
time_vec = [datetime.strptime(str(x),'%c') for x in data['time']]
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume I can do something like: %a %b %d %X %z %Y but It doesn't seem to work, I end up with "ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a%b%d%X%z%Y'"

Comment: Before anyone points out that this is a known issue http://bugs.python.org/issue6641 I am aware... However that doesn't actually provide an answer. I still need to be able to handle this date format.

Comment: have you seen: [Python strptime() and timezones?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3305413) or [How do I parse timezones with UTC offsets in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1302161/4279)

Comment: related: [How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101508/4279)

Comment: related: [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> s = "Sat Jan 17 04:33:06 +0000 2015"
>>> dt = parser.parse(s)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 17, 4, 33, 6, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

---

This is using the [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) package to [parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html) your string and return a datetime object.

---

Side note: The bug you reference indicates that the problem is resolved in Python 3.2. My assumption is that you are not using Python 3, thus have the error.

Answer (score 6):

Works fine for me...:

```
>>> s='Sat Jan 17 04:33:06 +0000 2015'
>>> f='%a %b %d %X %z %Y'
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s,f)
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 17, 4, 33, 6, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

This is in Python 3.4.  In Python 2.7, I can reproduce your bug -- it doesn't accept the `%z` as it should.  The best workaround is to upgrade to Python 3, of course.  If you just can't, you need some hack like:

```
import re

s = re.sub('[+-]\d+', '', s)
```

and remove the `%z` from the format.  If you do need that timezone info, extract it first (with a `re.search`, same pattern) before the `re.sub` to "clean up" `s` to work around the Python 2 bug.

Comment: the format expects a locale-dependent string (`%b`, `%X`). It might fail to parse the input if non-English locale is enabled.