# Time notation standard

Tags: python, timezone

I have the following script defining a `tzinfo` object:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo

class ManilaTime(tzinfo):
  def utcoffset(self, dt):
    return timedelta(hours=8)

  def tzname(self, dt):
    return "Manila"

manila = ManilaTime()
```

Now, I'm going to say

```
t = datetime(tzinfo=manila, *time.gmtime()[:-3])
print t
```

which gives me

```
2011-07-24 12:52:06+08:00
```

**Question:** What does `12:52:06+08:00` mean? I want to learn how to read time information which includes a UTC offset, according to standards. Please disregard that I used `time.gmtime()`. Let's say I only got the time string itself. How do I read it?

**A.** I need to perform the addition to get Manila Time. Upon reading this, I should make a calculation and I'll say

> It's `12:52:06` in Greenwich, which I should offset by `+08:00`. Meaning, it is `20:52:06` in Manila.

**B.** I'll take it at face value and say

> It's `12:52:06` in Manila, and it's offset from UTC by `+08:00`. Meaning, it is `04:52:06` in Greenwich.

Which is correct? **A** or **B**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`12:52:06+08:00` in general means it's the given time in a timezone 8 hours ahead of UTC. So **B** would be correct.

However, you **generated the time string incorrectly**. `time.gmtime()` just returns a time, without any timezone, and you told `datetime()` that time was in the Manilla time zone. So for this particular case, **A** would be correct.

Note: `datetime.strptime` doesn't work with timezones -- you can use the `%z` format code for `datetime.strftime`, but not with `strptime`. If you need to do this, use `dateutil`, see [How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python)