# dateutil.parser.parse() gives error "initial_value must be unicode or None, not str" on Windows platform

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I'm sure there's a really simple solution to this, but I'm still fairly new to Python.

I'm trying to use dateutil.parser.parse() to parse a string with a timestamp in it:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> a = dateutil.parser.parse("2011-10-01 12:00:00+01:00")
>>> print a
2011-10-01 12:00:00+01:00
```

This works fine on my Linux server, but on my Windows test box it gives an error:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> a = dateutil.parser.parse("2011-10-01 12:00:00+01:00")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg\dateutil\parser.py", line 698, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg\dateutil\parser.py", line 302, in parse
    res = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg\dateutil\parser.py", line 350, in _parse
    l = _timelex.split(timestr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg\dateutil\parser.py", line 144, in split
    return list(cls(s))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg\dateutil\parser.py", line 44, in __init__
    instream = StringIO(instream)
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
```

If I try giving dateutil.parser.parse() a unicode string, that doesn't work on the Windows box either:

```
>>> a = dateutil.parser.parse(unicode("2011-10-01 12:00:00+01:00"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg\dateutil\parser.py", line 698, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg\dateutil\parser.py", line 302, in parse
    res = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg\dateutil\parser.py", line 350, in _parse
    l = _timelex.split(timestr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg\dateutil\parser.py", line 144, in split
    return list(cls(s))
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type '_timelex'
```

Yet this also works on the Linux box.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not a Windows issue, it's Python version / library version issue.

dateutil 2.0 is written to support only Python 3, not Python 2.X. Both cases here contain bugs when used with Python 2.X.

In the first case:

```
dateutil.parser.parse("2011-10-01 12:00:00+01:00")
```

the `io.StringIO` class allows only unicode arguments, but the code reads:

```
    if isinstance(instream, str):
        instream = StringIO(instream)
```

In the second case:

```
dateutil.parser.parse(unicode("2011-10-01 12:00:00+01:00"))
```

if you look at `_timelex` class, it contains the `__next__` method, which is Python3's way of indicating that an object supports iteration protocol. In Python 2.X, the name of the method should be `next`.

Check if you have the same versions of both Python and the library on Linux and Windows. From [project website](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

> python-dateutil-2.0.tar.gz (Python >= 3.0)
>
> python-dateutil-1.5.tar.gz (Python < 3.0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I used easy_install to install dateutil for me on the Windows box (it was already installed on the Linux box).  Seems it installed the wrong one (Dateutil 2.0 on Python 2.7).

Comment: Thanks. Ran into the same issue because I am very bad and don't always use --no-site-packages in my virtualenvs.