# Facebook timestamp to Python DateTime Object

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, datetime, python-datetime

Facebook returns 'created_time' in this format:

```
2012-07-23T08:52:04+0000
```

I want to convert this timestamp to a normal Python DateTime object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil/)

It's extremely easy to use

```
import dateutil.parser as dateparser
dateparser.parse('2012-07-23T08:52:04+0000')
```

`dateutil` is very helpful to deal with `timezone` info, and it can handle lots of time formats.

Comment: Discussion on using dateutil in python2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "2005-12-06T12:13:14"
from datetime import datetime
from time import strptime
print datetime(*strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")[0:6])
```