# How to convert Python datetime object to specific timezone in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework, timezone

I'm working on an existing codebase which implements an api using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and the [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). When you post a datetime like this:

```
2019-06-21T10:35:46+02:00
```

it is stored in UTC as `2019-06-21 08:35:46+00` (as expected). This is because I've got `USE_TZ = True`.

When I serve the data, I also want it to be converted to the localised format again (`2019-06-21T10:35:46+02:00`). So following [this tip](https://fixes.co.za/django/make-django-rest-framework-date-time-fields-timezone-aware/) I implemented it like this:

```
class DateTimeFieldWihTZ(serializers.DateTimeField):
    """ Class to make output of a DateTime Field timezone aware """
    def to_representation(self, value):
        value = timezone.localtime(value)
        return super(DateTimeFieldWihTZ, self).to_representation(value)


class PeopleMeasurementSerializer(HALSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PeopleMeasurement
        fields = [
            '_links',
            'id',
            'timestamp',
            'sensor',
            'count'
        ]

    timestamp = DateTimeFieldWihTZ(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But this serves it as `2019-06-21 08:35:46`. How can I serve it as `2019-06-21T10:35:46+02:00` again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [set `TIME_ZONE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE) in your `settings.py`. It should work out of the box just with putting `'timestamp'` in the `fields` list.

To make it explicit, you could also write

```
timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(format='iso-8601')
```

Note that I'm assuming you're working with one main timezone for all your responses. If you need to return the time with the timezone the user sent, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14714819/2616577).