# Convert time string with timezone info to iso format

Tags: python-2.7, python-datetime

How to convert a time string with time zone information to a iso format string?

eg:

Time string with time zone info

```
time = "2012-01-01T10:30:00-05:00"
```

ISO format time string

```
time = "2012-01-01T15:30:00Z"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def timestamp(time):
    form dateutil import parser
    time = parser.parse(time) #Converts string in to datetime object 
    from pytz import UTC
    if time.tzinfo: #Checks if the time is aware or naive
        time = time.astimezone(UTC) #Converts aware time into UTC
    return time.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
```