# Why %z is not supported by python's strptime?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, strptime, python-datetime

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2014-02-13 11:55:00 -0800', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 317, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
```

I understand that it's not supported, but don't know why. Seems it's not hard to support that. And '[Offset from UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC)' is not as ambiguous as timezone abbreviation.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python

Comment: @IanStevens: that says nothing about *why*.

Comment: There's some speculation under a comment in that link. The linked mailing list archive, https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2003-November/021063.html, suggests it's a feature of libc: "it's not a Python bug but a bug in the platform libc." Whether or not that's still true, I don't know.

Comment: That's a bug report about `time.strptime()` though. The reliance on the libc parser has long since been replaced by a [pure-Python implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/90dab7696e89/Lib/_strptime.py) used by both the `time.strptime()` and `datetime.datetime.strptime()` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until Python 3.2, Python's `datetime` module *had no `timezone()` object*. It supported 3rd-party libraries providing timezones by providing a [`datetime.tzinfo()` abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects), but no timezone object was included. Without a timezone object, no support for parsing timezone offsets either.

As of Python 3.2, `z` is supported, because that version (and up) added a [`datetime.timezone()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2014-02-13 11:55:00 -0800', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 13, 11, 55, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 57600)))
>>> _.tzinfo
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 57600))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix for python 2.7

Instead of using:

```
datetime.strptime(t,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M %z')
```

use the `timedelta` to account for the timezone, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
def dt_parse(t):
    ret = datetime.strptime(t[0:16],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
    if t[18]=='+':
        ret+=timedelta(hours=int(t[19:22]),minutes=int(t[23:]))
    elif t[18]=='-':
        ret-=timedelta(hours=int(t[19:22]),minutes=int(t[23:]))
    return ret
```