# What datetime format string is 2017-01-05T14:23:33.986-0500 in Python

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
t = "2017-01-05T14:23:33.986-0500"
```

I need to convert it to a Python date.

I used:

```
t_obj = datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I think it is in YYYY-MM-DD with time as HH:MM:SS.sss , but am not able to figure out what -0500 could be...could it be subtracting -5 hrs for UTC?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: t printed out to 2017-01-09T14:01:37.347-0500
and when I tried t_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')  ...I get a bad directive error    as follows ....Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in 
    t_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 317, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

Comment: if I try t= "2017-01-05T14:23:33.986-0500"
dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')..then I get the following error....Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in 
    dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
NameError: name 'dt' is not defined....

Comment: That works for me but I'm running python 3.4, it should work as you seem to be running python 2.7, are you able to upgrade?

Comment: No, I cannot upgrade....if I try the following code.............import datetime as dt

dt=dt.datetime.strptime("2017-01-05T14:23:33.986", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
print dt.........................it works, but if I try import datetime as dt

dt=dt.datetime.strptime("2017-01-05T14:23:33.986-0500", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
print dt....it gives the z bad directive error......

Comment: It should work on python 2.7 unless there is some bug in datetime module for python 2.7

Comment: Actually this looks like a bug in 2.7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python can you at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python in particular this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165659/python-timezone-z-directive-for-datetime-strptime-not-available/38992623#38992623

Answer (score 4):

`%z` is what you need it's the timezone offset from UTC, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

> %z - UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the the object
>   is naive).    (empty), +0000, -0400, +1030

```
In [89]:
t= "2017-01-05T14:23:33.986-0500"
dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')

Out[89]:
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5, 14, 23, 33, 986000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)))
```

Answer (score 0):

EdChum's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41508805/1426065) is definitely correct. However, there is an easier way to go about parsing dates - [`python-dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("2017-01-05T14:23:33.986-0500")
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5, 14, 23, 33, 986000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```

The [`parse()`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) function is very robust and able to handle a wide variety of date formats:

```
>>> parse("Friday January 6, 2017 11:12 AM")
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 6, 11, 12)
```

This is on 3.6.0 with `dateutil` 2.6.0.