# How to make python datetime.strptime take into account timezone passed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, strptime

Trying to convert a string to `datetime` and save it to db. The string specifies the timezone, but `strptime` doesn't accept the `%z` option.

```
datetime.strptime("Tue Feb 14 2017 15:30:01 GMT-0500", "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z")
```

> ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z'

Comment: The answer looks to be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165659/python-timezone-z-directive-for-datetime-strptime-not-available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%z` is supported since Python 3.2.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("Tue Feb 14 2017 15:30:01 GMT-0500", "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z")
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 15, 30, 1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)))
```

---

Or use [`dateutil.parser`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html?highlight=parser),

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('Tue Feb 14 2017 15:30:01 GMT-0500')
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 15, 30, 1, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 18000))
```

---