# convert python datetime with timezone to string

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I have date time tuples in the format of `datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

How can I convert that into a date time string such as `2008-11-10 17:53:59`

I am really just getting held up on the tzinfo part.

`strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` works fine without the tzinfo part

Comment: '%z' if you are using `python3` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165659/python-timezone-z-directive-for-datetime-strptime-not-available

Comment: the < is giving me an invalid syntax error

Comment: strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") works fine for me. Can you give an example about how the time tuples are constructed and what error you got?

Comment: this would help http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/converting-time-zones-datetime-objects-python/

Comment: I am getting exactly this from the query datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>) I am not sure how the tuples are created

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The way you seem to be doing it, would work fine for both timezone aware and naive datetime objects. If you want to also add the timezone to your string, you can  simply add add it with %z or %Z, or using the `isoformat` method:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta, datetime, tzinfo

>>> class UTC(tzinfo):
...     def utcoffset(self, dt):
...         return timedelta(0)
... 
...     def dst(self, dt):
...         return timedelta(0)
... 
...     def tzname(self,dt):
...          return "UTC"

>>> source = datetime(2010, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=UTC())
>>> repr(source)
datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<__main__.UTC object at 0x1054107d0>)

# %Z outputs the tzname
>>> source.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
'2010-07-01 00:00:00 UTC'

# %z outputs the UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM
>>> source.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
'2010-07-01 00:00:00 +0000'

# isoformat outputs the offset as +HH:MM or -HH:MM
>>> source.isoformat()
'2010-07-01T00:00:00+00:00'
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `isoformat` method, very useful indeed. Thanks for sharing