# Python strptime ``%z``

Tags: python, iso8601, strptime, strftime

*EDIT2*: This question is assuming a POSIX-ish platform with Python
linked against Glibc.

On my system, round-trip conversion using the `%z` formatting directive
using Python’s *time* library fails to parse the offset part of ISO 8601
formatted timestamps. This snippet:

```
import time
time.daylight = 0
fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ%z"
a=time.gmtime()
b=time.strftime(fmt, a)
c=time.strptime(b, fmt)
d=time.strftime(fmt, c)

print ("»»»»", a == c, b == d)
print ("»»»»", a.tm_zone, b)
print ("»»»»", c.tm_zone, d)
```

outputs:

```
»»»» False False
»»»» GMT 2018-02-16T09:26:34Z+0000
»»»» None 2018-02-16T09:26:34Z
```

whereas the expected output would be

```
»»»» True True
»»»» GMT 2018-02-16T09:26:34Z+0000
»»»» GMT 2018-02-16T09:26:34Z+0000
```

How do I get `%z` to respect that offset?

- Python 3.3.2 and 3.6.4
- [Glibc 2.17 and 2.25 ⇒ see below!]

*EDIT*: Glibc can be acquitted as proven by this C analogue:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

/* 2018-02-16T09:59:21Z+0000 */
#define ISO8601_FMT "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ%z"

int main () {
    const time_t t0 = time (NULL);
    struct tm a;
    char b [27];
    struct tm c;
    char d [27];

    (void)setenv ("TZ", "UTC", 1);
    tzset ();
    daylight = 0;

    (void)gmtime_r (&t0, &a);                       /* a=time.gmtime () */
    (void)strftime (b, sizeof(b), ISO8601_FMT, &a); /* b=time.strftime (fmt, a) */
    (void)strptime (b,            ISO8601_FMT, &c); /* c=time.strptime (b, fmt) */
    (void)strftime (d, sizeof(d), ISO8601_FMT, &c); /* d=time.strftime (fmt, c) */

    printf ("»»»» b ?= d %s\n",  strcmp (b, d) == 0 ? "yep" : "hell, no");
    printf ("»»»» %d <%s> %s\n", a.tm_isdst, a.tm_zone, b);
    printf ("»»»» %d <%s> %s\n", c.tm_isdst, c.tm_zone, d);
}
```

Which outputs

```
»»»» b ?= d yep
»»»» 0 <GMT> 2018-02-16T10:28:18Z+0000
»»»» 0 <(null)> 2018-02-16T10:28:18Z+0000
```

Comment: I have another error with the zone name being generated with `Z`. `%z` does the same here (python 3.4), I never get 0000 or something.

Comment: that seems to depend on the underlying libc python was compiled/linked with. The `%z` format returns "Paris, Madrid" for me....

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165659/python-timezone-z-directive-for-datetime-strptime-not-available

Answer (score 2):

With the "time.gmtime()" naturally you are getting the UTC time, so the offset will be always +0000, therefore an output string "2018-02-16T09:26:34Z" is correct for the ISO8601. If you want absolutely the "+0000" add it manually because it will be alway the same:

```
d = time.strftime(fmt, c) + '+0000'
```

Comment: The timestamp is correct on the first invocation of ``strftime()``. Then ``strptime()`` results in a ``time.struct_time`` object with different values: ``.tm_zone`` field is *None*  instead of *"GMT"*, and ``.tm_isdst`` has *-1* instead of *0*. I’d expect these to be preserved as they are with the obsolete ``%Z`` specifier.

Comment: Changed in version 3.3: tm_gmtoff and tm_zone attributes are available on platforms with C library supporting the corresponding fields in struct tm. [link](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.strptime). Also my plattform doesn t support it.

Comment: Can u use the datetime library? Normally I used it to solve these kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't pretend to have the solution to generate the proper hour shift according to the time zone, but I can explain what happens here.

As hinted in [Python timezone '%z' directive for datetime.strptime() not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165659/python-timezone-z-directive-for-datetime-strptime-not-available) answers:

- `strptime` is implemeted in pure python so it has a constant behaviour
- `strftime` depends on the platform/C library it was linked against.

On my system (Windows, Python 3.4), `%z` returns the same thing as `%Z` ("Paris, Madrid"). So when `strptime` tries to parse it back as digits, it fails. Your code gives me:

```
ValueError: time data '2018-02-16T10:00:49ZParis, Madrid' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ%z'
```

It's system dependent for the generation, and not for the parsing.

This dissymetry explains the weird behaviour.

Comment: You may assume a POSIX-ish platform with a sane implementation of *strftime(3)*. Also FWIW I’m not using *datetime* but *time*.

Comment: datetime and time probably use the same underlying C library.

Comment: The C library is innocent, see the updated question.

Comment: the C library may not be the GCC library. On windows, a lot of things use microsoft native even through MinGW. Ex: `printf` format specifiers.

Comment: That’s irrelevant. I stated in the question that my Python is linked against Glibc.