# time data '2021-06-10T18:39:41 10:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z'

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to pass a datetime string with a timezone offset into a Django url as a query param as follows:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/coordinates/12.231/34.322/?obstime=2021-06-10T18:39:41+1000
```

I'm attempting to parse this in the view as follows:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(
    self.request.query_params.get('obstime'),
    "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z"
).isoformat()
```

So I'm utilising the format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z".

I thought this would work, however I am seeing the following error:

```
time data '2021-06-10T18:39:41 1000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z'
```

I've tried to search for potential fixes for this error, but so far everything has come up dry.

Does anyone know the correct format I need to pass in to either the url endpoint or to the `datetime.datetime.strptime()` function...

Comment: [The documentation for the `%z` format](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) says: "UTC offset in the form `±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]`". `10:00` doesn't seem to match this format

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, but in the URL I am passing it in the correct format: `?obstime=2021-06-10T18:39:41+1000`

Comment: Yeah, I've just noticed this. Not sure why this happened...

Comment: `+` in a URL can be interpreted as a space. Try using `%2B` instead in the URL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20#:~:text=A%20URL%20is%20a%20Uniform,page%20(in%20most%20cases).&text=For%20HTTP%20URLs%2C%20a%20space,part%20can%20be%20left%20unencoded.

Comment: Personally I would have done it differently, I would have used a timestamp, less headache that way and less different symbols in the url. You'd be able to interpret it simply by having `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(self.request.query_params.get('obstime'))).isoformat()` (though would be better to check if it is numeric before trying to cast it to int).

Answer (score 1):

According to the URL encoding rules, `+` becomes   (space). If you want to use the `+` sign in the URL, you must substitute `%2B`.

Not ok:

```
?obstime=2021-06-10T18:39:41+1000 
(this becomes ?obstime=2021-06-10T18:39:41 1000)
```

Ok:

```
?obstime=2021-06-10T18:39:41%2B1000 
(this becomes ?obstime=2021-06-10T18:39:41+1000)
```

Also, you omitted the space sign. Perhaps if you request the URL like this, it will be handled normally.

```
?obstime=2021-06-10T18:39:41+%2B1000
(this becomes ?obstime=2021-06-10T18:39:41 +1000)
```

Related: [How to encode the plus (+) symbol in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450190/how-to-encode-the-plus-symbol-in-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the '+'.

```
a_result = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-06-10T18:39:41 +1000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z')
print('a result', a_result)

a result 2021-06-10 18:39:41+10:00
```

This will parse with out a space, so you need some token between the seconds and the timezone. I was able to make these work for India's 5:30 time zone

```
a_result = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-06-10T18:39:41+05:30', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(a_result)

2021-06-10 18:39:41+05:30
```

I also found this [Python timezone '%z' directive for datetime.strptime() not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165659/python-timezone-z-directive-for-datetime-strptime-not-available/38992623)