# String to Time Python strptime

Tags: python, strptime

I'm pulling the date value from gmail and trying to perform some functions on it. First I simply want to display it, but I can't even do that. See my code and error below.

```
from datetime import datetime
timeString = 'Sat, 2 Aug 2014 09:29:31 -0700'
myTime = datetime.strptime(timeString, '%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p')
```

Here's the error I get. Do you think its the -0700 that's getting in the way?

```
ValueError: time data 'Sat, 2 Aug 2014 09:29:31 -0700' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you need to put the same format as your date string is in, I've not tried it, but something like this should work:

```
myTime = datetime.strptime(timeString, '%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %z')
```

Check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for complete details.

Comment: `%z` is not supported by `datetime.strptime` as of python 2.6 according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python) however your code runs on my Python 3.4.1, so I guess this is highly version-specific.

Comment: @AdamSmith You are right, %z was removed in python 2.6, however this has again been added to python 3.2+ versions.