# Convert string string to datetime object

Tags: python, string, datetime

My string is ,

```
str='2014-09-24T15:18:57+0000'
```

and I am trying to convert this string to valid datetime object. How to do that ?

What I tried is ,

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(str,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.strptime(str,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: +0000
```

But When I tried to change string to `str='2014-09-24T15:18:57'` it works fine,

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2014-09-24T15:18:57','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 24, 15, 18, 57)
```

Whats wrong with `+0000` ,  How to avoid first error ?

Answer (score 2):

How about adding to your pattern `%z` that stands for [UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the the object is naive)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

So the pattern will look like `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z`.

If you don't want the `+0000` and it will always be in your `str` you can change your code to `datetime.strptime(str[:-5],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: `%z` is supported only since Python 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a string and this pattern

```
2014-09-24T15:18:57+0000
%Y  -%m-%dT%H:%M:%S[    ]
```

And you're missing the +0000

Two options:

1. Get rid of +0000
2. Add something to your pattern

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import datetime
dt_str='2014-09-24T15:18:57+0000'
new_dt = dt_str[:19]
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Whats wrong with +0000 , How to avoid first error ?

`+0000` is a UTC offset, you could use `%z` directive to parse it (since Python 3.2):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> time_string = '2014-09-24T15:18:57+0000'
>>> datetime.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 24, 15, 18, 57, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

`%z` is not available on older Python versions. If all timestamps have the same UTC offset `+0000` then you could parse it as:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 24, 15, 18, 57)
```

Notice: the value is a naive datetime object (no timezone info).
To attach the tzinfo, for older Python versions, see [How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122493/4279)