# Convert weird Python date format to readable date

Tags: python, date

I am using Python to access the mobile API of some web service and the response contains the following weird Date notation: `u'/Date(1409522400000+0200)/'` This should be the 1st of September, 2014.

I am not sure which format this is, but I would like to convert this to something readable, i.e. a `date` or a `datetime` or Unix time.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Can you tell us what the actual date of that example is?

Comment: It should be the 1st of September 2014, I think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The time string looks like [OData version 2 JSON verbose format for Datetime that may be seen in old ASP.NET or WCF applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26541769/4279):

> “/Date(<ticks>[“+” | “-” <offset>])/”
>   <ticks> = number of milliseconds
>   since midnight Jan 1, 1970
>   <offset> = utc offset

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

time_string = u"/Date(1409522400000+0200)/"
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
ticks, offset = re.match(r'/Date\((\d+)([+-]\d{4})?\)/$', time_string).groups()
utc_dt = epoch + timedelta(milliseconds=int(ticks))
print(utc_dt)
if offset:
   offset = int(offset)
   hours, minutes = divmod(abs(offset), 100)
   if offset < 0:
      hours, minutes = -hours, -minutes
   dt = utc_dt.astimezone(timezone(timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes)))
   print(dt)
```

#### Output

```
2014-08-31 22:00:00+00:00
2014-09-01 00:00:00+02:00
```

where [`timezone` is defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22330133/4279).

Answer (score 4):

you received a (java?) timestamp in milliseconds. you can convert it to something more readable like so:

```
from datetime import date

d=1409522400000/1000.0 # divide by 1000 to get seconds
print date.fromtimestamp(d) # -> 2014-09-01
```

Comment: `date.fromtimestamp()` returns date in the local timezone.  It may be different from the source timezone specified in the input string e.g., if the local timezone is UTC then your code returns `2014-08-31` while the correct value is   the different date [`2014-09-01 00:00:00+02:00`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28507530/4279)