# Parsing timezone information with datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timezone, rfc3339

i' ve a string i' d like to parse and create a datetime object from it. For example:

```
2013-07-09T11:21:32+0500
```

. Using

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(str(dt)[0:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

will do the half of the work, but what can i do with the timezone information? How can combine it with datetime if this is in this form?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your python version. As Python 3.2+ supports `%z`. For earlier versions look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python.

Comment: python 2.7.9 unfortunately.

Comment: I think you should look at the linked answer and at dateutil