# difference between 2 dates in seconds with timezone using standard modules python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, seconds

How to find the difference between 2 dates in `seconds` with `timezone` only using the python standard modules such as `datetime`, `time` etc.. not with `dateutil`, `pytz` etc... This is not a duplicate question.

```
from datetime import datetime
t2 = datetime.strptime('Sun 4 May 2015 13:54:36 -0600', "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
t1 = datetime.strptime('Sun 4 May 2015 13:54:36 -0000', "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
diff = (t2 - t1).seconds
print diff
```

But it gives me error like, `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'`

I guess it is a `naive` object. So how to find the difference for `naive` object using `datetime` or `time` module.
Do we need to create our own function to do that?

Simple inputs:

```
'Sun 10 May 2015 17:56:26 +0430'
'Sat 09 May 2015 15:56:26 +0000'
```

If i could parse the date like this using,

```
from datetime import datetime
t2 = datetime.strptime('Sun 4 May 2015 13:54:36', "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
t1 = datetime.strptime('Sun 4 May 2015 13:54:36', "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
diff = (t2 - t1).seconds
print diff
```

Then how to handle the `timezone` info? Any hint will be helpful.

I could easily do this with dateutil module like

```
from dateutil import parser
t1 = parser.parse("Sun 4 May 2015 13:54:36 -0600")  
t2 = parser.parse("Sun 4 May 2015 13:54:36 -0000")  
diff = t1 - t2
print int(diff.total_seconds())
```

Comment: I believe that in Python 2.x (and early 3.x), `%z` is only supported for `strftime`, not `strptime`—although on some platforms (where the underlying C function supports it) it may work anyway. If so means if you don't want to upgrade to 3.x or use a third-party library, you'll have to split off the tzoffset, parse it yourself, and either (a) adjust the datetimes, or (b) an offset-only timezone object and apply it, creating aware datetimes.

Comment: `%z` doens't work because it depends on the OS. Not because it's a naive object. Take a look here how to fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python/23122493#23122493

Comment: @MartinKonecny: I think this counts as a dup of that question. Even though the question doesn't specify no third party libs, and the accepted answer uses `dateutil`, you'd be hard pressed to find a better answer than J.F. Sebastian's for this…