# Get time regardless of the Timezone/DST in python using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following string in python:

```
message = "2015-08-26T19:30:00+0200"
```

And I want to retrieve the time from it so I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
date=pd.to_datetime(message)
m=datetime.time(date)
```

The output is

```
17:30:00
```

How can I get `19:30` regardless of the DST

Comment: Shouldn't DST only adjust the time by 1 hour?  Aren't you really asking about the time zone (which, if you notice, is `+0200`?

Comment: `pandas.to_datetime` returns an object storing the date in UTC, and as far as I know, doesn't retain any information about which timezone the string was in.

Comment: Indeed I meant the Time zone (and the DST included in this time zone),
I thought that too.. but the output is using the timezone and I cant find a way to ignore it

Comment: your question is "how to get the local time (+0200 utc offset) instead of utc time."

Comment: related: [How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101508/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the strptime with the %z format and it worked

```
import datetime
message = "2015-08-26T19:30:00+0200"
fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
d=datetime.datetime.strptime(message, fmt)
print(d.time())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using arrow:

```
import arrow
message = "2015-08-26T19:30:00+0200"
m = arrow.get(message, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ')
print m.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ') # 2015-08-26T19:30:00+0200
print m.format('HH:mm:ss') # 19:30:00
```

Information about arrow is at http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/.