# python2.6.6 Convert apache log timestamp to seconds since epoch (unix style)

Tags: python, apache, datetime, python-2.6, epoch

As I am completely lost in the dozens of ways you find on stackoverflow to do timestamp conversions, so I will ask here the complete question:

Convert this timestamp from an apache log (in CEST timezone):

```
30/Aug/2015:05:13:53 +0200
```

Into this:

```
1440904433
```

Using

```
$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

Verification:

```
$ date --date @1440904433
Sun Aug 30 05:13:53 CEST 2015
$ date -u --date @1440904433
Sun Aug 30 03:13:53 UTC 2015
```

Bad results are:

```
1440911633
1440908033
```

My current code goes until here:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("30/Aug/2015:05:13:53 +0200".replace(':',' ',1))
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 30, 5, 13, 53, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))
```

Please do not propose pytz module, I don't have it and I can't install it.
Please do not propose solutions for python3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two steps:

1. **Convert the time string into an aware datetime object** (or a naive `datetime` object that represents time in UTC).

   ```
   >>> from dateutil import parser
   >>> parser.parse("30/Aug/2015:05:13:53 +0200".replace(':', ' ', 1))
   datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 30, 5, 13, 53, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))
   ```

   You've already done it. See [How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1101508/4279) on how to do it using only stdlib.
2. **Convert an aware datetime object to ["seconds since the Epoch"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html#tag_21_04_15)**:

   ```
   >>> from datetime import datetime
   >>> from dateutil import tz
   >>> td = d - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=tz.tzutc())
   >>> td
   datetime.timedelta(16677, 11633)
   >>> (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 86400) * 10**6) // 10**6
   1440904433
   ```

   Use `/` and enable  `from __future__ import division`, to get fractions of a second. If you don't need to support fractions; you could simplify the formula:

   ```
   >>> td.seconds + td.days * 86400
   1440904433
   ```

   If you get a utc time on the 1st step using only stdlib then you don't need `dateutil.tz` here. See [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)

Here's a Python 3 solution for visitors from a search engine:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime("30/Aug/2015:05:13:53 +0200", "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z")
>>> d.timestamp()
1440904433.0
```

Comment: This is what I need. Good that in python3 this has become less complex. you miss the `d=parser.parse("30/Aug/2015:05:13:53 +0200".replace(':',' ',1))` to be able to cut-paste your solution.