# How to convert string into datetime object in python?

Tags: python

I have date in following format

```
 d  = '2014-03-17 13:57:59-07:00'
```

How do I convert the above into timestamp object
The following works

```
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S-07:00")
```

But then 7 is hardcoded.. i am not sure what that is?
How do i ignore that part

Comment: @PadraicCunningham.. but in my data.. sometimes it is 7 and sometimes it is 8 or somethng else.. how do i parse it

Comment: Simplest way is to install and use `dateutil.parser.parse(d)`

Comment: You can also calculate it yourself by slicing

Comment: %z is the utc offset code, see http://strftime.org/ and try d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")

Comment: @TrisNefzger, that is not going to work, the format is not correct, %z also only works for python3.2+

Comment: This answer shows how to slice http://stackoverflow.com/a/23122493/2141635

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: thank you for pointing that out. With Python 3, time.strftime's %z directive unfortunately does not support colon in time zone offset. The colon could be removed with re.sub for a Python 3 solution and arrow suppports time zone offsets with and without a colon for Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) package which supports parsing a string to a datetime. You can install it by doing:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

And then:

```
import dateutil.parser

d = dateutil.parser.parse('2014-03-17 13:57:59-07:00')
```

The 7 or 8 in your dates is the offset from UTC - it is used to indicate in what timezone the datetime is located.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow has format directives for time zone offsets with and without a colon, functionality for converting to and from datetime objects and works with Python 2 and 3. Assuming that its been installed, which can be done with 'pip install arrow', here is how it can be used to convert '2014-03-17 13:57:59-07:00' to a datetime object:

```
import arrow
d = '2014-03-17 13:57:59-07:00'
f = 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ssZ'
d1 = arrow.get(d, f).datetime
```

Documentation for arrow is at http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/.