# Handling of timezones in strptime in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, timezone

I have two string like these:

```
"Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 -0700"
"Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 +0000"
```

(The last part is time zone -0700 means 7 hours less than GMT)

 My intention is turn it to a unix timestamp to find their absolute difference easily.


My Question is is there a built-in method for turning these formated texts to Unix timestamp? Or Is there a one that computes difference of two such strings directly??

**Edit:**
This Question differs from [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345)  since that problem doesn't include **time zones** and not any of answers to that question mentioned anything about time zone.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I couldn't find my answer in the question you  mentioned, since no one told anything about time zones there :-(

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python?

Comment: @schwobaseggl the dateutil seems perfect but it is not bundled with python standard library, I will edit the question properly.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @Vishwa I use hackerrank.com python2 or I could use python 3 If it solves any problem

Comment: @schwobaseggl one of the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python actually works with datetime module only , but just with python 3.2+ I could use that , Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on Python 3 & above but not known to work on all platforms on Python 2.

```
date_str = "Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 -0700"
pattern =  '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
dt = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_str ,pattern )))
print(dt)
```

For, Python 2.7+, (without `%z`)

```
import datetime
date_str = "Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 -0700"

dt_str = date_str[:-5].strip()
dt_zone = int(date_str[-5:])/100
pattern =  '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S'

dtobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str ,pattern)
dt = dtobj + datetime.timedelta(hours=dt_zone)
print( dt.strftime('%s') )
```

Comment: @Fazel did it not work?

Comment: The Python 2 solution doesn't work for timezones with fractional-hour offset.

Comment: additionally you've got an extra strip

Answer (score 0):

This code answer to your question:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, tzinfo
date1="Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 -0700"   

date2=date1[4:-6]

zone = int(date1[-5:])/100

d=datetime.strptime(date2, "%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")

class TZ(tzinfo):
   def utcoffset(self, dt): return timedelta(hours=zone)

d=datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day,d.hour,d.minute,d.second, tzinfo=TZ()).isoformat(' ')


print d
```

Comment: Even if it does work, is very questionable coding IMO, including such things as throwing away the minutes of the original offset and using a global variable as a default value in a method..

Comment: What is coding IMO

Comment: In my opinion. The other answer has similar issues.

Comment: Yeh, you are wright, I did not see it when i put my code