# datetime.strptime(‘2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500’,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, strptime, python-datetime

I've been trying to convert this specific date format to a string in Python like so:

```
datetime.strptime(‘2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500’,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')
```

But it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41684991/edit) to show the output or error message you get, compared to what you expect.  Thanks!  **Also**, use straight quotes `''`, not curly quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution for Python 2.7

From the comments it became clear that OP needs a solution for Python 2.7.

Apparently, there's no `%z` in strptime for python 2.7 even though [the documentation claims the contrary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), the raised error is `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000%z'`.

To solve this, you need to parse the date without timezone first and add the timezone later. Unfortunately you need to subclass `tzinfo` for that. This answer is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122493/119861)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo

class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    """offset_str: Fixed offset in str: e.g. '-0400'"""
    def __init__(self, offset_str):
        sign, hours, minutes = offset_str[0], offset_str[1:3], offset_str[3:]
        offset = (int(hours) * 60 + int(minutes)) * (-1 if sign == "-" else 1)
        self.__offset = timedelta(minutes=offset)
        # NOTE: the last part is to remind about deprecated POSIX GMT+h timezones
        # that have the opposite sign in the name;
        # the corresponding numeric value is not used e.g., no minutes
        '<%+03d%02d>%+d' % (int(hours), int(minutes), int(hours)*-1)
    def utcoffset(self, dt=None):
        return self.__offset
    def tzname(self, dt=None):
        return self.__name
    def dst(self, dt=None):
        return timedelta(0)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'FixedOffset(%d)' % (self.utcoffset().total_seconds() / 60)

date_with_tz = "2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500"
date_str, tz = date_with_tz[:-5], date_with_tz[-5:]
dt_utc = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
dt = dt_utc.replace(tzinfo=FixedOffset(tz))
print(dt)
```

The last line prints:

```
2017-01-12 14:12:06-05:00
```

Comment: Thank you @hansaplast this was exactly what I needed since I'm working with an ancient version of Python :P

Comment: well.. I wouldn't call python 2.7 ancient, it's still widely used by people who don't want to do the switch to python 3 (or their modules don't support python 3 yet)

Answer (score 14):

The error was that you used `%Z` instead of `%z`. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), you should use `%z` to match e.g. `(empty), +0000, -0400, +1030`

```
import datetime

result = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
2017-01-12 14:12:06-05:00
```

Comment: The problem is I'm using python 2.6 and it doesn't seem to recognize %z:

Answer (score 6):

Assuming Python 3, the format `%f` may not be a valid format character for `strptime` on your platform.  The [`strptime` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) reference [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) for the formats, and `%f` isn't in [the `strftime` list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime).  However, the [format string reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) says that

> The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common.

On my test system, which is Cygwin with Py 3.4.5, I used:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')
```

and got

```
ValueError: time data '2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z'
```

I checked the man pages for `strftime(3)` and found that I don't have `%f`, and `%z` should be lowercase.  I therefore used

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000%z')
#          straight quotes ^ not curly                  ^
#                                                      literal .000 (no %f) ^^^^ 
#                                                                  lowercase %z ^^
```

and got a successful parse.

**Edit** @Tagc found that `%f` worked fine running under Python 3.5 in PyCharm on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: This is incorrect. `%f` is a valid format character according to the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: @Tagc It actually depends on which documentation you read, and it turns out it's platform-specific.  Please see edited answer.

Comment: Ah okay. I'm confused so I'll lift my downvote. FWIW the `%f` worked fine for me running under Python 3.5 in PyCharm on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: @Tagc Thanks!  Yes, I was unpleasantly surprised to discover the internal inconsistency in the documentation.  Thanks for the extra data!

Answer (score 4):

**Task:**

"convert this specific date format to a string in Python"

```
import datetime
```

**Solution:**

First modify your `datetime.strptime` code as follows:

```
  obj = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

[This](http://strftime.org) is a useful site for your reference and will help you modify the output as per your preference.

Then use `strftime` to convert it to a string:

```
obj.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Out:

```
'Jan 12 2017 14:12:06'
```

Answer (score 4):

Having date as the input str:

```
from dateutil import parser
parsed_date = parser.parse(date)
```

[python-transforming-twitter](https://dzone.com/articles/python-transforming-twitter)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have timezone information, replacing the '%Z' with 'Z' works in Python 3.

```
datetime.strptime('2010-10-04T03:41:22.858Z','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
# datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 4, 3, 41, 22, 858000)
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is a string, e.g. load from a JSON file, you can try

```
date = '2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500'

print(date = date[:10]+" "+date[11:19])
```

returns:

```
2017-01-12 14:12:06
```