# convert 2021-01-18T11:18:10.833876+00:00 to datetime python

Tags: python, date, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am trying to convert the following string to datetime in python. After referring to [datetime.strptime(‘2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500’,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684991/datetime-strptime-2017-01-12t141206-000-0500-y-m-dthms-fz) I am trying the below mentioned format.

```
config_current_ts = datetime.strptime(internal_config["timestamp_str"], "%Y:%m:%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

Yet I get an error stating :

> ValueError: time data '2021-01-18T11:18:10.833876+00:00' does not
> match format '%Y:%m:%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

I am using python3.7.4. Can someone tell me how to convert this to datetime? I want to basically compare the string and current time to see which is ahead.

Comment: your strptime directive has `:` what should be `-` (date part).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Python 3.7+, use `fromisoformat` - since you have ISO 8601 format, it is appropriate and as a benefit also [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710371/10197418). Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime
s = '2021-01-18T11:18:10.833876+00:00'
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(s)

print(dt)
# 2021-01-18 11:18:10.833876+00:00
print(repr(dt))
# datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 18, 11, 18, 10, 833876, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

the format string should be `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'`

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = '2021-01-18T11:18:10.833876+00:00'
>>> datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 18, 11, 18, 10, 833876, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```