# Error when parsing string to datetime using datetime.strptime() in ISO 8601 format in Python

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to parse a string as a datetime, put it as a new timezone (CEST UTC+02) and return it, but I get this error:

```
> ValueError: time data '2022-07-04T03:15:00Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

Example input:

```
2022-07-04T03:15:00Z
2022-07-04T12:40:20Z
2022-07-04T11:56:08Z
```

Example output:

```
2022-07-04T05:15:00+02:00
2022-07-04T14:40:20+02:00
2022-07-04T13:56:08+02:00
```

Code:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

str = "2022-07-04T03:15:00Z"
str = (datetime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z') + timedelta(hours=2)).isoformat()
print(str)
```

I also tried:

```
str = (datetime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000%z') + timedelta(hours=2)).isoformat()
```

and:

```
str = (datetime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fz') + timedelta(hours=2)).isoformat()
```

as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41685087/18336250) and by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402779/18336250):

Comment: Try with `"2022-07-04T03:15:00.000Z"`

Comment: Dupe of [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date) - also, you might want to have a look at [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is incorrect, remove the [`.%f`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), you have no microseconds:

```py
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

s = "2022-07-04T03:15:00Z"
s = (datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z') + timedelta(hours=2)).isoformat()
print(s)
```

Output: `2022-07-04T05:15:00+00:00`

Comment: "*Output: 2022-07-04T05:15:00+00:00*" - shouldn't that be +02:00 ? ;-) Maybe suggest how to handle time zones / UTC offsets properly, see comment under the question