# How to parse 'Apr 21, 2021, 7:43:51 AM GMT+5:30' into timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

there are date strings like `'Apr 21, 2021, 7:43:51 AM GMT+5:30'` (downloaded from google spreadsheet into CSV).

What are these date formats?
How to parse them into a timestamp?

**Update**

I have a function:

```
def to_timestamp(s):
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(s, '%b %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p')
    return datetime_object.timestamp()
```

but I have no idea how to process `GMT+5:30`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Have you tried pandas.to_datetime() with the format parameter?

Comment: @Woodford

I have no idea how to parse `GMT+5:30`. Any idea?

Comment: you could try the `Cell Formatting` section in the Google Spreadsheet before exporting as CSV to change the date format to your desired style.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch the timezone format:

```
import re

def to_timestamp(s):
    s = re.sub(r'([+-])(\d{1}):', '\g<1>0\g<2>:', s)
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(s, '%b %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p %Z%z')
    return datetime_object.timestamp()

s = 'Apr 21, 2021, 7:43:51 AM GMT+5:30'
d = to_timestamp(s)
```

```
>>> d
1618971231.0
```